# TypeError: $(...).get(...) is undefined when trying to open a .txt file with input type text

Tags: jquery, html, file

I'm trying to read a .txt file, split in into lines and then console.log it. So far I'm getting this error when I try to read the file. Please tell me what I'm doing wrong.

```js
$("#draftLogInput").change(function () {

    //gets first file from draftlog
    var filenumber = $('#draftlog').get(0).files.length;
    filenumber--;
    logFile = $('#draftlog').get(0).files[filenumber];

    //reads file from draftlog as text
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.readAsText(logFile);
    reader.onload = function (e) {
        var rawLog = reader.result;

        //splits the text into an array of strings for every new line
        var re = /\r\n|\n\r|\n|\r/g;
        var SplitLog = rawLog.replace(re, "\n").split("\n");

        console.log(SplitLog);
    };
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="file" id="draftLogInput">
```

Comment: In you sample the `input` has the id `draftLogInput`  and not `draftlog`. If this is really the case then `$('#draftlog')`  won't find that element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using

```
   var filenumber = $('#draftlog').get(0).files.length;
    filenumber--;
    logFile = $('#draftlog').get(0).files[filenumber];
```

Use:

```
   var filenumber = $('#draftLogInput')[0].files.length;
    filenumber--;
    logFile = $('#draftLogInput')[0].files[filenumber];
```

You have no element with the ID `dreaftlog`. So your selector is getting an empty array.

Comment: Why should the OP change `.get(0)` to `[0]`?

Comment: ugh, I copied the code from another version of the same app I made and forgot to recheck all ids, thanks for pointing this out.

Comment: Well I'm pretty sure you did, because you wrote about the `.get` before you deleted, edited and undeleted. Anyway in an answer you should only change the relevant parts or explain why you changed other parts.